# Is it still true that using pointers is significantly faster than using the array syntax in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, performance

With current C compilers, is it still true that using the array syntax (a[i]) is slower than using pointers (*(p+i))?

Comment: By the way, it has never been true :)

Comment: I'm believe I read it on the "C programming language", although a very old edition. So it might have been true in some distant past...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They should be the same. But:

```
for( i = 0; i < ...; ++ i ) ... array[i] ...
```

could be slower than:

```
for( p = array; *p; ++ p ) ... *p ...
```

because in the former case compiler could need to do `*(array+i)`, while in the second you just do `(*p)`.

In trivial cases, however, compiler should be able to optimize and generate the same machine code.

Comment: instead of "might be able" I would say "should be able" :)

Comment: Indeed, "might be able" was correct. For example, older versions of some compilers (namely, MSVC) compiled the first example into a more efficient code.

Comment: @Vlad A compiler may not do it, you are right, but it should, because if it doesn't, it is a bad compiler :) IMHO

Comment: There are a lot of embedded compilers that can't do this optimization.  When working with a new compiler/platform, be sure to try both and look at the assembly listing file to be sure they generate equivalent code.

Comment: By the way, in the second code compiler might be unable to prove that `p` cannot be altered during the execution of the loop body; this could potentially prevent some optimizations. If `i` is defined locally (close to the actual loop), a sophisticated compiler may potentially make use of it.

Answer (score 11):

They are exactly equivalent. Array access is syntactic sugar for pointer math.

Comment: This isn't necessarily true.  Assuming `a` is an array and `p` is a pointer, then `a[i]` involves adding a constant and a variable, whereas `p[i]` involves adding two variables.

Answer (score 8):

No, according to the C and C++ standards `a[i]` is by definition equivalent to `*(a+i)`. this also implies that `a[1]` is equivalent to `1[a]`. Try it :)

Comment: @Fernando: You think that's odd? `if(3["hello"] =='l')` is odder :)

Answer (score 5):

Hell No! `a[i]` is always equivalent to `*(a+i)`.

[`a[i] = *(a + i) = *(i + a) =i[a];`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a/381549#381549)

Answer (score 3):

On x86 or x86_64, using `p[i]` or `*(p+i)` (note: these two forms are identical in the C language) may be faster than incrementing `p` at each step of the loop, assuming you need to keep `i` around for some other purpose already. The x86 architecture has efficient addressing for base/offset usage like this, including scaling the offset by small powers of 2.

On the other hand, if you can eliminate `i` by incrementing `p`, you may reduce the number of registers needed in you loop, which could allow further optimization. Here are some quick thoughts on the relative cost in various cases on x86:

- If you array `a` has static storage duration (`static` or `extern` global) in non-PIC-compiled code, the `a[i]` and `*p` (with no `i`) methods use the same number of registers (e.g. `0xdeadbeef(,%ecx,4)` vs `(%esi)`).
- If Your array `a` is automatic (local stack variable) and not a variable-length array, the `a[i]` and `*p` methods use the same number of registers (e.g. `12(%esp,%ecx,4)` vs `(%esi)` where `%esp`, the stack pointer, is already reserved anyway).
- If your array `a` has static storage duration and your code is compiled as PIC, `a[i]` is probably significantly more expensive than the `*p` method, even if you have to keep `i` around for another purpose anyway.
- If your array `a` is not an array variable in the current scope, but a pointer to an array passed to your function from somewhere else, then `a[i]` takes one more register than `*p` (e.g. `(%eax,%ecx,4)` vs `(%esi)`).

Answer (score 2):

There may be some circumstances where something like

```
while (*s++ = *d++)
   ;
```

might be faster than

```
while (s[i] = d[i])
   i++;
```

but even that will probably be optimized away by good compilers.

Comment: If none of the 3 variables are used after the loop, a good compiler will generate the same code for both sources. However, a lot of code *does* depend on the values - either it wants to keep using the original `s` and `d` pointers (in which case, "optimizing" the second loop to the first would require backign up and restoring their values), or wants to use the final value of `i` (in which case the optimization would need to save the original value of `s` or `d` and subtract at the end). Not that it can't be done, but issues like these complicate the situation a good bit.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler will translate them to pointer code anyway, it just makes it easier to use them.

Think of array operator as an inline function for the pointer equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

They are equivalent. But algorithms that use the array syntax are typically written

```
int a[];
for (int n = 0; n < size; n++) { ... Do stuff with a[n]; }
```

which needs one more addition for each access to an element of `a` than

```
int a[size];
int *end = a + size;
for (int *i = a; i != end; ++i) { ... Do the same stuff with *i ; }
```

Some compilers might optimize the first version into the second though.

Answer (score 1):

It's obvious that's not what he means, this should help.

```
// which is faster? *t or t[i]?
process_some_array(T *t, size_t n)
{
    T *end = &t[n];
    for (T *t = t; t < end; ++t)
        // do stuff with *t
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        // do stuff with t[i]
}
```

The answer is not as long as your compiler has no optimization whatsoever. For the general case you should not worry about the difference, as it is miniscule if present at all. Furthermore it's generally easier for yourself, and your fellows to parse and debug.

If this is not what you meant, I'm afraid it's a stupid question, see one of the other answers.

Comment: ++ for good thinking, but BTW, if you use an adjective that implies an insult, even if only conditionally applied, it feels to the author like a punch in the gut. It took me a long time to learn that too.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer and Array both are accessing through address.Array is behave like a constant pointer and pointer used to hold the address of any value.So same thing is both access the value through address. On account of that both are exactly equivalent.